# Spring application root variable

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I access my Spring application right now as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app
```

In my JSPs I'd like to have access to my application root instead of hardcoding hyperlinks to the homepage as `<a href="/my-app">`.  Is there some sort of variable that I can access in my jsps to point to the application root?  Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. For example, to get `href = "/my-app/somePage"`, use:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/somePage">
```

However, this approach doesn't support URL rewriting required to maintain sessions in the case of disabled cookies. So, the better way to do it is JSTL's `<c:url/>` tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<a href="<c:url value = '/somePage' />">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the context root with `getContextPath()` on the request object.